# JSON encoder generating JSON message adding empty quotes characters in BizTalk 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-2016

My XML message

```
<ns0:rootNode xmlns:ns0="http://project.Schemas.rootNode">  
  <bitmap></bitmap>
</ns0:rootNode>
```

after json encoder converting, below is the

```
{
      "bitmap": ""
}
```

but I'm expecting in below format

```
{
      "bitmap": null
}
```

For some reason BizTalk 2013 R2 able to convert it as expected, but BizTalk 2016 is not able to do the same.

I have tried by making bitmap to string, boolean and datetime datatypes, but not able to make it.

Is there any suggestions or custom pipeline is the only one option I have?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the current behavior of Biztalk 2016 JSON Encoder

**Input XML:**

```
<test>
    <a></a>
    <b>test</b>
    <c>NULL</c>
    <d/>
</test>
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "test": {
    "a": "",
    "b": "test",
    "c": "NULL",
    "d": null
  }
}
```

In order to generate json null values, elements should be in self closing tag form

Answer (score 0):

So they fixed an issue that existed in BizTalk 2013 R2 as per my blog post, [BizTalk 2013 R2 known bugs, issues & quirks](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/).

> **Issue**: The BizTalk JSON Encoder changes blanks in XML to null in JSON
> **Details**: If you use the JSON Encoder and have a element that is empty, it becomes a null in the JSON payload.
> **More Details**: [REST JSON Christmas Puzzle](https://connectedpawns.wordpress.com/2015/12/24/rest-json-christmas-puzzle/)
> **Work Around**: Use the [BRE Pipeline](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework) and do a Replace the string `": null` in the message body with the string `": ""` (initial concept from [REST JSON Christmas Puzzle – Work around](http://%20REST%20JSON%20Christmas%20Puzzle%20%E2%80%93%20Work%20around)).
> **Note**: The above work around has an unintended side effect that it causes a BOM to be added. This may cause issues with some systems.

If you want to have it `null`, maybe you need to set the xsd nillable property to true on that field in the schema and have `xsi:nil="true"` set in the payload.

Other than that, you would have to do the opposite of the fix we had to implement for BizTalk 2013 R2.